# How to include javascript code in asp.net MVC4 View page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to asp.net MVC4 architecture i am get stuck with following thing please help me.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#sections").tabs();
    //here i am getting error that Object[object object] has not method tabs    
});
</script>

<div id="sections">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section-1">section-1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-2">section-2 </a></li>
    </ul>
        <div id="section-1">
        section-1 content............  
        </div>
        <div id="section-2">
        section-2 content............ 
        </div>
    </div>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have included the `~/bundles/jquery` bundle twice. Checkout your `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file. At the end you probably have the following:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

So the jQuery bundle is already included in your page. You should not include it a second time inside your view. You need only the `~/bundles/jqueryui` bundle:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#sections").tabs();
    //here i am getting error that Object[object object] has not method tabs    
});
</script>

<div id="sections">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section-1">section-1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-2">section-2 </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="section-1">
        section-1 content............  
    </div>
    <div id="section-2">
        section-2 content............ 
    </div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's a full example of how the structure of your view might look like:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Foo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sections">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#section-1">section-1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-2">section-2 </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="section-1">
            section-1 content............  
        </div>
        <div id="section-2">
            section-2 content............ 
        </div>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#sections").tabs();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply...but when i remove @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") this line it says $ is not defined...

Comment: You should not remove the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` line. You should remove the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` line if it already exists in your `_Layout.cshtml`. Is this the case? I have updated my answer with an example of how your view might look.

Comment: How do you do this , when you are not using bundler? (or any other minifcation.) I get the same behavior as the OP. Its included in the _Layout, but then I also have to include it in every page I want to use JavaScript in. Else I get $ not defined.